# Autocomplete adding extra spaces

Tags: javascript

**Image Example**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Image Example Keyboard**

[image: Screen Shot]

My auto commplete is adding extra spaces when data is selected from web services, how do i fix this?
i've tried mostly everything but isnt getting any results

**Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/jz1e4tr6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                 source: function (request, response) {
                     $.ajax({
                         url: '<%=ResolveUrl("/Normal/WebServices/AutoComplete.asmx/GetSubject")%>',
                         data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                         dataType: "json",
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         success: function (data) {
                             response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                 return {
                                     label: item.split('-')[0],
                                     attr: item.split('-')[1]
                                 }
                             }))
                         },
                         error: function (response) {
                             alert(response.responseText);
                         },
                         failure: function (response) {
                             alert(response.responseText);
                         }
                     });
                 },
```

Comment: What kind of extra spaces? White spaces arround the value? In that case, isn't it fixable using the js trim function?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding extra spaces"? Could you provide example of your autocomplete provider response, what you expect to see in autocomplete, and what you actually get?

Comment: If i start typing "Sem" the data gets lastname from my database through webservices.

when i click on the full name which is 'semeleer' i get 'semeleer                                   ' with all the blank spaces

it should be 'Semeleer'

Comment: image is in top

Comment: And what your `data` looks like in this case?

Comment: @Cyberskunk its in a SQL Server database,

Data type = varchar(50)

its a last name examples:

Smith
Johnson
Williams
Jones

When i start typing Jo

The results should be:
Jones
Johnson

when i click Johnson in the auto complete box.

the data in my textbox becomes:
Johnsonxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
With x being spaces.
and when it reads back from the database it gets no results because in my database there is no Johnson with so mane characters

Comment: Yes, I see. I mean what's in ajax response. You can try to log `data` variable to console, use debugger to check its value, or just see the response in Network tab of the browser developer tools

Comment: https://ibb.co/ex9h3Q

Comment: @cyberskunk ibb.co/ex9h3Q

Comment: Almost there: now select your AJAX request and open its `Response` in the pane on the right-hand side

Comment: @cyberskunk yes, and its JSON d:

https://ibb.co/hzSp05

Comment: @cyberskunk can you help?

Comment: I wish I could. Your last screenshot shows that there're four fields in the response, not the whole data. My initial thought was to look into the response and check that it is what you expect it to be: seems there's no code which could cause described behavior and the problem could be in the data.

Comment: @cyberskunk i found an alternative "tweak" but not the right solution...
before clicking submit in the code behind...

i get the value from the textbox and into a variable.
And trim the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative "tweak" but not the right solution... before clicking submit in the code behind... i get the value from the textbox and into a variable. And trim the variable.